# Unity Playground PICKUP & HOLD script not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity Playground with students and we are trying to use the PICK-UP AND HOLD script, but we don't think it is working properly. We have everything mentioned in the reference guide on the object, but the character doesn't pick up the object. When the is trigger is marked the player will just go through the object. When the is trigger is marked off, the player will collide with the object and it moves. Clicking the button to pick up the object just causes the object to float through colliders but the game object doesn't follow the character. I am guessing something is wrong with the parent-child part of the script but unsure as there are no errors. Here is the script down below.

Thanks!

[PICKUP Script Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82mQc.png)
[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Xz4.png)

Comment: In `play mode > scene view > hierarchy`, do you see the pickup being nested under the gameobject in which `PickUpAndHold.cs` is attached?

Comment: Also a side note. You should generate the csproj files for your unity game so that people have intellisense https://forum.unity.com/threads/intellisense-not-working-with-visual-studio-fix.836599/

Comment: Please include code as properly formatted text, not as images.

Comment: I do not see it being nested under the game object. Also, thanks for the heads up about intellisense. To include code as properly formatted text, is it a simple copy and paste or something else? I just felt the pictures would be easier on the eyes if it is copy and paste.

Comment: So when I tested this using the above script I see the `pickup` being nested under the object that has the script attached to it. So you may just need to double check what that script is attached to.

Comment: Yeah, you can copy paste the code as is and then use the "Code Sample" button (`{}`) in the StackOverflow editor for code highlighting.